# How to set due time in timer(_:period:scheduler:)

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I have learned RxSwift for a period of time by following the book named Reactive Programming with swift. There are some tutorials about timer operator that I cannot understand

```
let elementsPerSecond = 1
let delayInSeconds = 2
let sourceObservable = PublishSubject<Int>()

var current = 1
let timer = DispatchSource.timer(interval: 1.0 / Double(elementsPerSecond), queue: .main) {
    sourceObservable.onNext(current)
    sourceObservable2.onNext(current)
    current = current + 1
}

_ = sourceObservable.subscribe(sourceTimeline)

_ = sourceObservable
.delay(RxTimeInterval(delayInSeconds), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
.subscribe(delayedTimeline)

_ = Observable<Int>
.timer(RxTimeInterval(0), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
.flatMap { _  in
    return sourceObservable.delay(RxTimeInterval(delayInSeconds), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
}
.subscribe(timerTimeline)
```

But the result is very strange:
[image]

The third view is timerTimeline and it was second behind second timeline which is delayedTimeline. So where is the second goes? What's more, the first element was ignored by the timerTimeline. I don't know how to use the timer operator and could anyone tell me the reason, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is a strange example indeed, especially the first half of it.
As for your questions I guess the missing second is a mistake (should be *'.timer(RxTimeInterval(1)'*), and the first element ('1') is skipped because *flatMap()* was executed only when it was already gone.

Comment: You said that the first element ('1') is skipped because flatMap() was executed only when it was already gone. I still can't make sense and can you explain in detail. Thank you

Comment: I mean if we assume that it is indeed *'.timer(RxTimeInterval(1)'*, then the code inside *flatMap()* will be executed after the 1st element of * sourceObservable* is already replaced by the 2nd. And consumed by the *delayedTimeline* subscription.